# ¿Cómo puedo convertir un arreglo JSON en una List <T>?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

En mi servidor obtengo una cadena JSON con este método :

```
 public string  GetCadenaJson()
            {
                string resultado = string.Empty;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = Engine.FuncionesDb.TableDataCliente();
                List<Cliente> Customer = new List<Cliente>();
                if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    return resultado;
                }
                else
                {
                 Customer = SetListaCliente(dt);
                 resultado = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Customer);
                }

                return resultado;
            }

    private List<Cliente> SetListaCliente (DataTable dt)
            {
                List<Cliente> Customer = new List<Cliente>();
                foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Cliente lineaCliente = new Cliente
                    {
                        Numero = Convert.ToInt32(r[0]),
                        Id = r[1].ToString(),
                        Nombre = r[2].ToString(),
                        Edad = Convert.ToInt32(r[3]),
                        Telefono = r[4].ToString(),
                        Mail = r[5].ToString(),
                        Saldo = Convert.ToDouble(r[6]),
                        FechaCreacion = Convert.ToDateTime(r[7]),
                        FechaCreacionUtc = Convert.ToDateTime(r[8]),
                        FechaModificacion = Convert.ToDateTime(r[9]),
                        FechaModificacionUtc = Convert.ToDateTime(r[10]),
                        Proceso = Convert.ToInt32(r[11]),
                        Usuario = r[12].ToString(),
                        Estado = r[13].ToString(),
                    };
                    Customer.Add(lineaCliente);
                }
                return Customer;
            }


    public class Cliente
        {
            public int Numero { get; set; }

            public string  Id { get; set; }

            public string Nombre { get; set; }

            public int Edad { get; set; }

            public string Telefono { get; set; }

            public string Mail { get; set; }

            public double  Saldo  { get; set; }

            public DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }

            public DateTime FechaCreacionUtc { get; set; }

            public DateTime FechaModificacion { get; set; }

            public DateTime FechaModificacionUtc { get; set; }

            public int Proceso { get; set; }

            public string Usuario { get; set; }

            public string Estado { get; set; }
        }
```

Necesito en mi cliente convertir esa cadena en un objeto List del mismo tipo Cliente y hago esto… Pero me devuelve:

> ERROR: No se puede convertir el objeto de tipo 'System.String' en
>   el tipo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ApiRestConsumer.Form1+Cliente]'"}  System.InvalidOperationException

```
private string ClientGetRequest(string RequestURI)
    {
        string resultado = string.Empty;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50445/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response = client.GetAsync(RequestURI).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            resultado = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

           List<Cliente> Customer = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Cliente>>(resultado);

        }
        else
        {
            resultado = response.IsSuccessStatusCode.ToString();
        }

        return resultado;
    }
```

¿Cómo puedo resolver este error?

```
[
   {
      "Numero":14,
      "Id":"a22f9dde-468a-4699-9dea-106d32368f88",
      "Nombre":"jose",
      "Edad":324,
      "Telefono":"352",
      "Mail":"dfsf",
      "Saldo":34,
      "FechaCreacion":"\/Date(1533814172047)\/",
      "FechaCreacionUtc":"\/Date(1533839372047)\/",
      "FechaModificacion":"\/Date(1533814172047)\/",
      "FechaModificacionUtc":"\/Date(1533839372047)\/",
      "Proceso":0,
      "Usuario":"sdfff",
      "Estado":"ACTIVO"
   },
   {
      "Numero":11,
      "Id":"d4391326-719b-4ceb-bad6-4356ca2c49e2",
      "Nombre":"we",
      "Edad":234,
      "Telefono":"324",
      "Mail":"jmiranda",
      "Saldo":3240,
      "FechaCreacion":"\/Date(1533778195383)\/",
      "FechaCreacionUtc":"\/Date(1533803395383)\/",
      "FechaModificacion":"\/Date(1533778195383)\/",
      "FechaModificacionUtc":"\/Date(1533803395383)\/",
      "Proceso":0,
      "Usuario":"usuario",
      "Estado":"ACTIVO"
   },
   {
      "Numero":6,
      "Id":"aa155af9-5198-429c-a7b2-5ed59fb24a97",
      "Nombre":"jose",
      "Edad":234,
      "Telefono":"234",
      "Mail":"sd",
      "Saldo":324,
      "FechaCreacion":"\/Date(1533746659797)\/",
      "FechaCreacionUtc":"\/Date(1533771859800)\/",
      "FechaModificacion":"\/Date(1533746659800)\/",
      "FechaModificacionUtc":"\/Date(1533771859800)\/",
      "Proceso":0,
      "Usuario":"dsg",
      "Estado":"ACTIVO"
   },
   {
      "Numero":3,
      "Id":"5361a270-83ca-49cd-be56-63ba29d5109a",
      "Nombre":"Juan Gonzalez",
      "Edad":67,
      "Telefono":"0416-23446789",
      "Mail":"juan@yahoo.com",
      "Saldo":9876456.79878,
      "FechaCreacion":"\/Date(1533672699633)\/",
      "FechaCreacionUtc":"\/Date(1533687099633)\/",
      "FechaModificacion":"\/Date(1533672699633)\/",
      "FechaModificacionUtc":"\/Date(1533687099633)\/",
      "Proceso":0,
      "Usuario":"Efrain",
      "Estado":"ACTIVO"
   },
   {
      "Numero":9,
      "Id":"f150db8d-42ba-4bbe-b91d-7bb3d72fe23e",
      "Nombre":"joseito",
      "Edad":324,
      "Telefono":"432",
      "Mail":"jmiranda",
      "Saldo":234,
      "FechaCreacion":"\/Date(1533754909823)\/",
      "FechaCreacionUtc":"\/Date(1533780109833)\/",
      "FechaModificacion":"\/Date(1533754909890)\/",
      "FechaModificacionUtc":"\/Date(1533780109893)\/",
      "Proceso":0,
      "Usuario":"usuario",
      "Estado":"ACTIVO"
   },
   {
      "Numero":10,
      "Id":"cb8225c1-6080-4973-a170-961591dba402",
      "Nombre":"daniel",
      "Edad":20,
      "Telefono":"04121903020",
      "Mail":"jmiranda",
      "Saldo":240,
      "FechaCreacion":"\/Date(1533755485563)\/",
      "FechaCreacionUtc":"\/Date(1533780685573)\/",
      "FechaModificacion":"\/Date(1533755485620)\/",
      "FechaModificacionUtc":"\/Date(1533780685623)\/",
      "Proceso":0,
      "Usuario":"usuario",
      "Estado":"ACTIVO"
   },
   {
      "Numero":4,
      "Id":"ef04f8f7-8e4f-48e1-8829-9ea38f0c934f",
      "Nombre":"Juan Garcia ",
      "Edad":56,
      "Telefono":"0412-5678990",
      "Mail":"juangarcia@yahoo.com",
      "Saldo":1000000,
      "FechaCreacion":"\/Date(1533726827613)\/",
      "FechaCreacionUtc":"\/Date(1533752027613)\/",
      "FechaModificacion":"\/Date(1533726827613)\/",
      "FechaModificacionUtc":"\/Date(1533752027613)\/",
      "Proceso":0,
      "Usuario":"EfrainMejiasC",
      "Estado":"ACTIVO"
   },
   {
      "Numero":5,
      "Id":"a36623e6-b231-45a7-92e0-cf4010ed8eb1",
      "Nombre":"Carias Liscano",
      "Edad":89,
      "Telefono":"0426-555555",
      "Mail":"cariasliscano",
      "Saldo":0.6789,
      "FechaCreacion":"\/Date(1533727606777)\/",
      "FechaCreacionUtc":"\/Date(1533752806777)\/",
      "FechaModificacion":"\/Date(1533727606777)\/",
      "FechaModificacionUtc":"\/Date(1533752806777)\/",
      "Proceso":0,
      "Usuario":"EfrainMejiasCastillo",
      "Estado":"ACTIVO"
   },
   {
      "Numero":12,
      "Id":"0d4918e1-439f-4246-ac4f-e93057cf55f9",
      "Nombre":"trewrtwert",
      "Edad":34,
      "Telefono":"345345",
      "Mail":"juangarcia@yahoo.com",
      "Saldo":757567567,
      "FechaCreacion":"\/Date(1533811925033)\/",
      "FechaCreacionUtc":"\/Date(1533826325037)\/",
      "FechaModificacion":"\/Date(1533811925037)\/",
      "FechaModificacionUtc":"\/Date(1533826325037)\/",
      "Proceso":0,
      "Usuario":"hfghfghfghf",
      "Estado":"ACTIVO"
   },
   {
      "Numero":8,
      "Id":"eea8056e-578b-4701-bd1f-ec543a0a16ae",
      "Nombre":"maria Mujica ",
      "Edad":34,
      "Telefono":"04265432190",
      "Mail":"mail.eryw@hotmail.com",
      "Saldo":4532753,
      "FechaCreacion":"\/Date(1533752400510)\/",
      "FechaCreacionUtc":"\/Date(1533777600510)\/",
      "FechaModificacion":"\/Date(1533752400510)\/",
      "FechaModificacionUtc":"\/Date(1533777600510)\/",
      "Proceso":0,
      "Usuario":"EfrainMejias",
      "Estado":"ACTIVO"
   },
   {
      "Numero":16,
      "Id":"c00fdd3e-fd5a-4bc0-b60e-f23c0b4e54a9",
      "Nombre":"ka",
      "Edad":34,
      "Telefono":"325",
      "Mail":"mail",
      "Saldo":324,
      "FechaCreacion":"\/Date(1533814471250)\/",
      "FechaCreacionUtc":"\/Date(1533839671250)\/",
      "FechaModificacion":"\/Date(1533814471250)\/",
      "FechaModificacionUtc":"\/Date(1533839671253)\/",
      "Proceso":0,
      "Usuario":"sf",
      "Estado":"ACTIVO"
   },
   {
      "Numero":2,
      "Id":"1eddb545-6811-44f3-b1d2-f379792aff3d",
      "Nombre":"Xiomara Telleria",
      "Edad":25,
      "Telefono":"0414-23446789",
      "Mail":"xiomara@cantv.com",
      "Saldo":12345345.678,
      "FechaCreacion":"\/Date(1533672651770)\/",
      "FechaCreacionUtc":"\/Date(1533687051770)\/",
      "FechaModificacion":"\/Date(1533672651770)\/",
      "FechaModificacionUtc":"\/Date(1533687051770)\/",
      "Proceso":0,
      "Usuario":"Efrain",
      "Estado":"ACTIVO"
   },
   {
      "Numero":13,
      "Id":"24333f93-0f16-4ecf-9550-fdc9b960cd8c",
      "Nombre":"mi nuevo cliente ",
      "Edad":30,
      "Telefono":"0412-4567832",
      "Mail":"minuevocliente@empresas.net",
      "Saldo":53267.6537845,
      "FechaCreacion":"\/Date(1533812379383)\/",
      "FechaCreacionUtc":"\/Date(1533826779387)\/",
      "FechaModificacion":"\/Date(1533812379387)\/",
      "FechaModificacionUtc":"\/Date(1533826779387)\/",
      "Proceso":0,
      "Usuario":"EfrainMejiasC",
      "Estado":"ACTIVO"
   },
   {
      "Numero":1,
      "Id":"85f9a04d-5406-4243-91e0-fef0c6c60a14",
      "Nombre":"Mariana Martinez",
      "Edad":22,
      "Telefono":"0416-23446789",
      "Mail":"mariana@cantv.com",
      "Saldo":1234.678,
      "FechaCreacion":"\/Date(1533672607013)\/",
      "FechaCreacionUtc":"\/Date(1533687007017)\/",
      "FechaModificacion":"\/Date(1533672607017)\/",
      "FechaModificacionUtc":"\/Date(1533687007017)\/",
      "Proceso":0,
      "Usuario":"Efrain",
      "Estado":"ACTIVO"
   }
]
```

Comment: Puedes poner el json que te devuelve la consulta?

Comment: Ese es el JSON de retorno

Comment: Tu JSon es correcto y la deserialización de primeras se ve bien. Has probado a declarar List<Cliente> Customer como var Customer? El resto lo dejas igual para que sepa que te lo tiene que desserializar el una lista de clientes

Comment: Como hacen aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033730/javascriptserializer-deserialize-array

Comment: O puedes utilizar esta librería también que es muy sencillo: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCollection.htm

Comment: var Customer = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Cliente>>(resultado);    me da el mismo error

Comment: Ninguno de los anteriores resolvio mi problema

Comment: Una pregunta, declaras result como un string. Cuánto vale result antes de intentar parsearlo?

Comment: result obtiene la cadena que muestro en el post ...un arreglo json con los atributos de la tabla cliente

Comment: En result que es un string no puedes almacenar un JSonArray, por eso te pregunto que, al hacer List<Cliente> Customer = new JavaScriptSerializer().D... cuanto vale result?

Comment: resultado = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            
  List <Cliente> jsonClientes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cliente>>(resultado);

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal el `JavaScriptSerializer` tenia algun problema al pasar de **string** a  **int** . Prueba cambiando el tipo de de tus enteros a **string**.

Comment: Igual el mismo error ...que sera?

Comment: ¿que librería estas usando?

Answer (score 0):

Siempre que trabajes con Json en C#, buenas, te recomiendo seguir los siguientes pasos

1. Generar tu clase con [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)
2. Deserializar con `var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);` **usando NewtonJson**

En tu caso json2sharp generaría lo siguiente:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int Numero { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Edad { get; set; }
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    public double Saldo { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaCreacionUtc { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaModificacion { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaModificacionUtc { get; set; }
    public int Proceso { get; set; }
    public string Usuario { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }
}
```

Luego, a fines de prueba, guardo tu response como un string ([Build My String](https://www.buildmystring.com/build.php), herramienta muy útil para estas situaciones)

```
            string sb = "[" +
"   {" +
"      \"Numero\":14," +
"      \"Id\":\"a22f9dde-468a-4699-9dea-106d32368f88\"," +
"      \"Nombre\":\"jose\"," +
"      \"Edad\":324," +
"      \"Telefono\":\"352\"," +
"      \"Mail\":\"dfsf\"," +
"      \"Saldo\":34," +
"      \"FechaCreacion\":\"\\/Date(1533814172047)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaCreacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533839372047)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacion\":\"\\/Date(1533814172047)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533839372047)\\/\"," +
"      \"Proceso\":0," +
"      \"Usuario\":\"sdfff\"," +
"      \"Estado\":\"ACTIVO\"" +
"   }," +
"   {" +
"      \"Numero\":11," +
"      \"Id\":\"d4391326-719b-4ceb-bad6-4356ca2c49e2\"," +
"      \"Nombre\":\"we\"," +
"      \"Edad\":234," +
"      \"Telefono\":\"324\"," +
"      \"Mail\":\"jmiranda\"," +
"      \"Saldo\":3240," +
"      \"FechaCreacion\":\"\\/Date(1533778195383)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaCreacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533803395383)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacion\":\"\\/Date(1533778195383)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533803395383)\\/\"," +
"      \"Proceso\":0," +
"      \"Usuario\":\"usuario\"," +
"      \"Estado\":\"ACTIVO\"" +
"   }," +
"   {" +
"      \"Numero\":6," +
"      \"Id\":\"aa155af9-5198-429c-a7b2-5ed59fb24a97\"," +
"      \"Nombre\":\"jose\"," +
"      \"Edad\":234," +
"      \"Telefono\":\"234\"," +
"      \"Mail\":\"sd\"," +
"      \"Saldo\":324," +
"      \"FechaCreacion\":\"\\/Date(1533746659797)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaCreacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533771859800)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacion\":\"\\/Date(1533746659800)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533771859800)\\/\"," +
"      \"Proceso\":0," +
"      \"Usuario\":\"dsg\"," +
"      \"Estado\":\"ACTIVO\"" +
"   }," +
"   {" +
"      \"Numero\":3," +
"      \"Id\":\"5361a270-83ca-49cd-be56-63ba29d5109a\"," +
"      \"Nombre\":\"Juan Gonzalez\"," +
"      \"Edad\":67," +
"      \"Telefono\":\"0416-23446789\"," +
"      \"Mail\":\"juan@yahoo.com\"," +
"      \"Saldo\":9876456.79878," +
"      \"FechaCreacion\":\"\\/Date(1533672699633)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaCreacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533687099633)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacion\":\"\\/Date(1533672699633)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533687099633)\\/\"," +
"      \"Proceso\":0," +
"      \"Usuario\":\"Efrain\"," +
"      \"Estado\":\"ACTIVO\"" +
"   }," +
"   {" +
"      \"Numero\":9," +
"      \"Id\":\"f150db8d-42ba-4bbe-b91d-7bb3d72fe23e\"," +
"      \"Nombre\":\"joseito\"," +
"      \"Edad\":324," +
"      \"Telefono\":\"432\"," +
"      \"Mail\":\"jmiranda\"," +
"      \"Saldo\":234," +
"      \"FechaCreacion\":\"\\/Date(1533754909823)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaCreacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533780109833)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacion\":\"\\/Date(1533754909890)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533780109893)\\/\"," +
"      \"Proceso\":0," +
"      \"Usuario\":\"usuario\"," +
"      \"Estado\":\"ACTIVO\"" +
"   }," +
"   {" +
"      \"Numero\":10," +
"      \"Id\":\"cb8225c1-6080-4973-a170-961591dba402\"," +
"      \"Nombre\":\"daniel\"," +
"      \"Edad\":20," +
"      \"Telefono\":\"04121903020\"," +
"      \"Mail\":\"jmiranda\"," +
"      \"Saldo\":240," +
"      \"FechaCreacion\":\"\\/Date(1533755485563)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaCreacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533780685573)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacion\":\"\\/Date(1533755485620)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533780685623)\\/\"," +
"      \"Proceso\":0," +
"      \"Usuario\":\"usuario\"," +
"      \"Estado\":\"ACTIVO\"" +
"   }," +
"   {" +
"      \"Numero\":4," +
"      \"Id\":\"ef04f8f7-8e4f-48e1-8829-9ea38f0c934f\"," +
"      \"Nombre\":\"Juan Garcia \"," +
"      \"Edad\":56," +
"      \"Telefono\":\"0412-5678990\"," +
"      \"Mail\":\"juangarcia@yahoo.com\"," +
"      \"Saldo\":1000000," +
"      \"FechaCreacion\":\"\\/Date(1533726827613)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaCreacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533752027613)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacion\":\"\\/Date(1533726827613)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533752027613)\\/\"," +
"      \"Proceso\":0," +
"      \"Usuario\":\"EfrainMejiasC\"," +
"      \"Estado\":\"ACTIVO\"" +
"   }," +
"   {" +
"      \"Numero\":5," +
"      \"Id\":\"a36623e6-b231-45a7-92e0-cf4010ed8eb1\"," +
"      \"Nombre\":\"Carias Liscano\"," +
"      \"Edad\":89," +
"      \"Telefono\":\"0426-555555\"," +
"      \"Mail\":\"cariasliscano\"," +
"      \"Saldo\":0.6789," +
"      \"FechaCreacion\":\"\\/Date(1533727606777)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaCreacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533752806777)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacion\":\"\\/Date(1533727606777)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533752806777)\\/\"," +
"      \"Proceso\":0," +
"      \"Usuario\":\"EfrainMejiasCastillo\"," +
"      \"Estado\":\"ACTIVO\"" +
"   }," +
"   {" +
"      \"Numero\":12," +
"      \"Id\":\"0d4918e1-439f-4246-ac4f-e93057cf55f9\"," +
"      \"Nombre\":\"trewrtwert\"," +
"      \"Edad\":34," +
"      \"Telefono\":\"345345\"," +
"      \"Mail\":\"juangarcia@yahoo.com\"," +
"      \"Saldo\":757567567," +
"      \"FechaCreacion\":\"\\/Date(1533811925033)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaCreacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533826325037)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacion\":\"\\/Date(1533811925037)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533826325037)\\/\"," +
"      \"Proceso\":0," +
"      \"Usuario\":\"hfghfghfghf\"," +
"      \"Estado\":\"ACTIVO\"" +
"   }," +
"   {" +
"      \"Numero\":8," +
"      \"Id\":\"eea8056e-578b-4701-bd1f-ec543a0a16ae\"," +
"      \"Nombre\":\"maria Mujica \"," +
"      \"Edad\":34," +
"      \"Telefono\":\"04265432190\"," +
"      \"Mail\":\"mail.eryw@hotmail.com\"," +
"      \"Saldo\":4532753," +
"      \"FechaCreacion\":\"\\/Date(1533752400510)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaCreacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533777600510)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacion\":\"\\/Date(1533752400510)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533777600510)\\/\"," +
"      \"Proceso\":0," +
"      \"Usuario\":\"EfrainMejias\"," +
"      \"Estado\":\"ACTIVO\"" +
"   }," +
"   {" +
"      \"Numero\":16," +
"      \"Id\":\"c00fdd3e-fd5a-4bc0-b60e-f23c0b4e54a9\"," +
"      \"Nombre\":\"ka\"," +
"      \"Edad\":34," +
"      \"Telefono\":\"325\"," +
"      \"Mail\":\"mail\"," +
"      \"Saldo\":324," +
"      \"FechaCreacion\":\"\\/Date(1533814471250)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaCreacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533839671250)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacion\":\"\\/Date(1533814471250)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533839671253)\\/\"," +
"      \"Proceso\":0," +
"      \"Usuario\":\"sf\"," +
"      \"Estado\":\"ACTIVO\"" +
"   }," +
"   {" +
"      \"Numero\":2," +
"      \"Id\":\"1eddb545-6811-44f3-b1d2-f379792aff3d\"," +
"      \"Nombre\":\"Xiomara Telleria\"," +
"      \"Edad\":25," +
"      \"Telefono\":\"0414-23446789\"," +
"      \"Mail\":\"xiomara@cantv.com\"," +
"      \"Saldo\":12345345.678," +
"      \"FechaCreacion\":\"\\/Date(1533672651770)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaCreacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533687051770)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacion\":\"\\/Date(1533672651770)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533687051770)\\/\"," +
"      \"Proceso\":0," +
"      \"Usuario\":\"Efrain\"," +
"      \"Estado\":\"ACTIVO\"" +
"   }," +
"   {" +
"      \"Numero\":13," +
"      \"Id\":\"24333f93-0f16-4ecf-9550-fdc9b960cd8c\"," +
"      \"Nombre\":\"mi nuevo cliente \"," +
"      \"Edad\":30," +
"      \"Telefono\":\"0412-4567832\"," +
"      \"Mail\":\"minuevocliente@empresas.net\"," +
"      \"Saldo\":53267.6537845," +
"      \"FechaCreacion\":\"\\/Date(1533812379383)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaCreacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533826779387)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacion\":\"\\/Date(1533812379387)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533826779387)\\/\"," +
"      \"Proceso\":0," +
"      \"Usuario\":\"EfrainMejiasC\"," +
"      \"Estado\":\"ACTIVO\"" +
"   }," +
"   {" +
"      \"Numero\":1," +
"      \"Id\":\"85f9a04d-5406-4243-91e0-fef0c6c60a14\"," +
"      \"Nombre\":\"Mariana Martinez\"," +
"      \"Edad\":22," +
"      \"Telefono\":\"0416-23446789\"," +
"      \"Mail\":\"mariana@cantv.com\"," +
"      \"Saldo\":1234.678," +
"      \"FechaCreacion\":\"\\/Date(1533672607013)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaCreacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533687007017)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacion\":\"\\/Date(1533672607017)\\/\"," +
"      \"FechaModificacionUtc\":\"\\/Date(1533687007017)\\/\"," +
"      \"Proceso\":0," +
"      \"Usuario\":\"Efrain\"," +
"      \"Estado\":\"ACTIVO\"" +
"   }" +
"]";
```

Por último,

```
//Deserealizo
List<RootObject> Modelo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(sb);


foreach(RootObject a in Modelo)
   {
   Console.WriteLine(a.Nombre);
   }
```

Salida de la consola:

```
jose
we
jose
Juan Gonzalez
joseito
daniel
Juan Garcia 
Carias Liscano
trewrtwert
maria Mujica 
ka
Xiomara Telleria
mi nuevo cliente 
Mariana Martinez
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad!

Respuesta basada en la de [L.B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22191376/5213794) en StackOverflow en Inglés

Comment: pruebo y te  comento

Comment: Que buena esta herramienta [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) ademas [hay un plugins para visual studio en el marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DangKhuong.JSONtoC)

Comment: Tambien esta en Visual Studio 2017 (creo que anteriores tambien) al instalar las herramientas de desarrollo web tienes la posibilidad de pegar un JSON como Clase (menu Editar  > Pegado Especial > Pegar JSON como Clase)

Answer (score 0):

. Viendo tu Json, efectivamente las fechas estan en formato Epoch (formato Unix time). Necesitas implementar un DateTimeConverter y establecerlo como atributo en tus propiedades de tipo fecha. Aqui te dejo un ejemplo

```
class Bookmark
{
    public string title;
    public long id;
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MicrosecondEpochConverter))]
    public DateTime dateAdded;
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MicrosecondEpochConverter))]
    public DateTime lastModified;
    public string type;
    public string root;
    public long parent;
    public List<Bookmark> children;
    public string uri;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} - {1}", title, uri);
    }
}

public class MicrosecondEpochConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
{
    private static readonly DateTime _epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue(((DateTime)value - _epoch).TotalMilliseconds + "000");
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value == null) { return null; }
        return _epoch.AddMilliseconds((long)reader.Value / 1000d);
    }
}

internal class Program
{

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@"T:/bookmarks-2013-11-13.json");
        var rootMark = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bookmark>(jsonString);
        var ret = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootMark);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yo hice rapidamemte un ejemplo por si te sirve,

Cree un [aplicación de consola (utilice .NET Core)](https://github.com/fernandezja/serialization-experiments-dotnet/tree/master/DeserializeJsonToListT) pero lo que si me ayude con el componente nuget archi-conocido de [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

1. Copie un objeto del JSON y lo pague como objeto desde el Visual Studio 2017 para que me cree la clase directamente. Pegar un JSON como Clase (menu Editar > Pegado Especial > Pegar JSON como Clase)
2. Luego solamente agregue la deserializacion de los datos en json a la List y me tomo completo

   ```
       var path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,  "data.json");

       var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@"data.json");
       var clientes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cliente>>(jsonString);
       Console.WriteLine($"Clientes cantidad: {clientes.Count}");
   ```

Algunas consideraciones:

- Al copiar lo hice con el primer objeto JSON y me tomo la propiedad
  *Saldo* como int y debe ser decimal

El objeto que se copio al pegar como JSON to class fue asi de simple

```
  public class Cliente
{
    public int Numero { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Edad { get; set; }
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    public decimal Saldo { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaCreacionUtc { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaModificacion { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaModificacionUtc { get; set; }
    public int Proceso { get; set; }
    public string Usuario { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }
}
```

Dejo por aqui el enlace al repositorio con el ejemplo

- [https://github.com/fernandezja/serialization-experiments-dotnet/tree/master/DeserializeJsonToListT)](https://github.com/fernandezja/serialization-experiments-dotnet/tree/master/DeserializeJsonToListT)

Ademas tambien probe seteando la configuracion de la fecha en la configuracion de serializacion con  DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat y me dio el mismo resultado [ya que se puede elegir cual es el formato con que viene la fecha o serializa](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateFormatHandling.htm). Pero como te comento igualmente detecto la fecha correcta.

```
      var path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,  "data.json");

        var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings(){
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
        };

        var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@"data.json");
        var clientes = JsonConvert
                        .DeserializeObject<List<Cliente>>(jsonString,
                                                          serializerSettings);
        Console.WriteLine($"Clientes cantidad: {clientes.Count}");
```